# Some kind of artifacts

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

Used boolean tool to create this dents on door, and when i use shade smooth some kind of lines appears.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=PweLN5oB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/PweLN5oB/)

Comment: can you pls upload the blend file without having the boolean applied? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just marked the circle as sharp and now everything is ok